# Windows batch file to extract env variables from text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

If I have a text file like this:

```
var1=3
var2=7
var3=Apple
```

Would it be possible in a Windows batch file (nothing fancy like PowerShell, it has to run on any Windows NT based PC) to iterate thru this list and generate an env variable (only needs to be accessble by script) so I can do this sort of thing:

```
for each var in vars/text file
    populate the vars

echo %var1%
echo %var2%
echo %var3%
```

Comment: Do you want it to set the Machine, User, or Session environment variables?  Use `setx` for the Machine and User and just `set` for the Session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f %%a in (varfile.txt) do set %%a

echo %var1%
echo %var2%
echo %var3%
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "delims=" %%A in (file.txt) do set "%%~A"

echo ...
endlocal
```